# How can I correct a Type Mismatch error using JSON Decoder in SWIFT even after changing the fields to match?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the SWIFT JSONDecocder to decode weather information from an API, the open weather API to be specific. I have created structs for the information I need to pull from the API.

The error is :

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "daily", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Here are my stucts

```
struct WeatherResponse: Codable {
let lat: Float
let lon: Float
let timezone: String
let current: CurrentWeather
let hourly: HourlyWeather
let daily: DailyWeather
let timezone_offset: Float

struct CurrentWeather: Codable {
let dt: Double
let sunrise: Double
let sunset: Double
let temp: Double
let feels_like: Double
let pressure: Double
let humidity: Double
let dew_point: Double
let uvi: Double
let clouds: Double
let visibility: Double
let wind_speed: Double
let wind_deg: Double

struct DailyWeather: Codable {
let data: [DailyWeatherEntry]

struct DailyWeatherEntry: Codable {
let dt: Double
let sunrise: Double
let sunset: Double
let temp: Double
let feels_like: Double
let pressure: Double
let humidity: Double
let dew_point: Double
let uvi: Double
let clouds: Double
let visibility: Double
let wind_speed: Double
let wind_deg: Double
 // let main: String
 // let description: String

struct HourlyWeather: Codable {
//let summary: String
//let icon: String
let data: [HourlyWeatherEntry]


struct HourlyWeatherEntry: Codable {
let dt: Double
let sunrise: Double
let sunset: Double
let temp: Double
let feels_like: Double
let pressure: Double
let humidity: Double
let dew_point: Double
let uvi: Double
let clouds: Double
let visibility: Double
let wind_speed: Double
let wind_deg: Double
```

The error comes at this line

```
var json: WeatherResponse?
        do {
            json = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherResponse.self, from: data)
        }
        catch {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
        
        guard let result = json else {
            return
        }
```

I've read in other posts to put my 'WeatherResponse' in square brackets to make It an array, but that leads to the following error "Cannot assign value of type '[WeatherResponse]' to type 'WeatherResponse?'". When putting 'WeatherRespsonse?' in square brackets, It invalidates the structs.

This is a portion of the data I am trying to decode:

```
"lat": 40.12,
"lon": -96.66,
"timezone": "America/Chicago",
"timezone_offset": -18000,
"current": {
"dt": 1595243443,
"sunrise": 1595243663,
"sunset": 1595296278,
"temp": 293.28,
"feels_like": 293.82,
"pressure": 1016,
"humidity": 100,
"dew_point": 293.28,
"uvi": 10.64,
"clouds": 90,
"visibility": 10000,
"wind_speed": 4.6,
"wind_deg": 310,
```

It continues in this fashion for hourly and daily as well.

Im new to all of this and I've been looking for hours trying to figure this out. Any advice?

Comment: Please add the JSON (ideally, minimally representable) that you're trying to decode, otherwise, how would we know why it's failing

Comment: I apologize about that. I added the data I am trying to decode as well. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: Have you looked at https://app.quicktype.io/?

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid JSON...

Comment: @Sweeper the JSON I posted is directly off of the OpenWeather API site. From what I read of the API, it's output is able to be decoded by JSON.

Comment: try changing  `let daily: DailyWeather` to `let daily: [DailyWeatherEntry]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Just tried It and It was looking good, but It ended up giving me an error as well. Now my hourly entries and my sunrise is incorrect.   Error is now "keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "sunrise", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "hourly", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"sunrise\", intValue: nil) (\"sunrise\").", underlyingError: nil))"

Comment: This error has nothing to do with your original error. If you don't post the whole json there is no way to help you parse the response.

Comment: @LeoDabus this is a link to the whole JSON that my program uses. https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.577862&lon=-101.855164&exclude=minutely&appid=1f16d9e6e4ff81acde25f67581255208

Comment: @ihateschoolsomuch check my post bellow

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your JSONDecoder `keyDecodingStrategy` is set to `.convertFromSnakeCase` and your data structure look like this:

---

Root.swift file contents

```
import Foundation

struct Root: Codable {
    let lat, lon: Double
    let timezone: String
    let timezoneOffset: Int
    let current: Current
    let hourly: [Current]
    let daily: [Daily]
}
```

---

```
struct Current: Codable {
    let dt: Int
    let sunrise, sunset: Int?
    let temp, feelsLike: Double
    let pressure, humidity: Int
    let dewPoint: Double
    let uvi: Double?
    let clouds, visibility: Int
    let windSpeed: Double
    let windDeg: Int
    let weather: [Weather]
    let pop: Int?
}
```

---

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: Main
    let weatherDescription: Description
    let icon: Icon
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, main, weatherDescription = "description", icon
    }
}
```

---

```
enum Icon: String, Codable {
    case the01D = "01d"
    case the01N = "01n"
    case the02D = "02d"
}
```

---

```
enum Main: String, Codable {
    case clear = "Clear", clouds = "Clouds"
}
```

---

```
enum Description: String, Codable {
    case clearSky = "clear sky", fewClouds = "few clouds"
}
```

---

```
struct Daily: Codable {
    let dt, sunrise, sunset: Int
    let temp: Temp
    let feelsLike: FeelsLike
    let pressure, humidity: Int
    let dewPoint, windSpeed: Double
    let windDeg: Int
    let weather: [Weather]
    let clouds, pop: Int
    let uvi: Double
}
```

---

```
struct FeelsLike: Codable {
    let day, night, eve, morn: Double
}
```

---

```
struct Temp: Codable {
    let day, min, max, night, eve, morn: Double
}
```

---

---

ViewController.swift  (Your view controller contents)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=33.577862&lon=-101.855164&exclude=minutely&appid=1f16d9e6e4ff81acde25f67581255208")!) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("URLSession error:", error ?? "")
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                let root = try decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
                print("Root:", root)
            } catch {
                print("JSONDecoder error:", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

This will print:

> Root: Root(lat: 33.58, lon: -101.86, timezone: "America/Chicago",
> timezoneOffset: -18000, current: OpenWeather.Current(dt: 1601440148,
> sunrise: Optional(1601383240), sunset: Optional(1601426059), temp:
> 291.04, feelsLike: 286.21, pressure: 1021, humidity: 25, dewPoint: 271.03, uvi: Optional(7.27), clouds: 1, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.6, windDeg: 220, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear, weatherDescription:
> OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon: OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)],
> pop: nil), hourly: [OpenWeather.Current(dt: 1601438400, sunrise: nil,
> sunset: nil, temp: 291.04, feelsLike: 285.41, pressure: 1021,
> humidity: 25, dewPoint: 271.03, uvi: nil, clouds: 1, visibility:
> 10000, windSpeed: 4.74, windDeg: 244, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601442000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 290.28, feelsLike: 284.8,
> pressure: 1020, humidity: 28, dewPoint: 271.81, uvi: nil, clouds: 1,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.69, windDeg: 252, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601445600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 289.39, feelsLike:
> 283.96, pressure: 1019, humidity: 31, dewPoint: 272.36, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.73, windDeg: 257, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601449200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 288.53, feelsLike:
> 283.17, pressure: 1018, humidity: 33, dewPoint: 272.45, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.66, windDeg: 261, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601452800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 287.96, feelsLike:
> 282.57, pressure: 1018, humidity: 34, dewPoint: 272.37, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.68, windDeg: 261, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601456400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 287.53, feelsLike: 282.2,
> pressure: 1017, humidity: 35, dewPoint: 270.43, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.6, windDeg: 262, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601460000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 287.1, feelsLike: 281.93,
> pressure: 1017, humidity: 36, dewPoint: 270.54, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.37, windDeg: 263, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601463600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 286.69, feelsLike:
> 281.73, pressure: 1017, humidity: 37, dewPoint: 270.74, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.07, windDeg: 270, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601467200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 286.41, feelsLike:
> 281.64, pressure: 1018, humidity: 38, dewPoint: 270.88, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.82, windDeg: 277, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601470800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 286.51, feelsLike:
> 281.83, pressure: 1018, humidity: 38, dewPoint: 271.26, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.71, windDeg: 279, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601474400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 289.71, feelsLike:
> 285.15, pressure: 1018, humidity: 32, dewPoint: 272.49, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.64, windDeg: 278, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601478000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 293.97, feelsLike:
> 289.25, pressure: 1018, humidity: 24, dewPoint: 273.19, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.81, windDeg: 282, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601481600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 297.38, feelsLike:
> 292.99, pressure: 1017, humidity: 20, dewPoint: 273.51, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.4, windDeg: 286, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601485200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 300.14, feelsLike:
> 296.44, pressure: 1017, humidity: 17, dewPoint: 273.23, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.42, windDeg: 280, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601488800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 302.28, feelsLike:
> 299.17, pressure: 1016, humidity: 15, dewPoint: 272.68, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.58, windDeg: 260, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601492400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 303.72, feelsLike:
> 300.76, pressure: 1015, humidity: 13, dewPoint: 272.3, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.19, windDeg: 217, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601496000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 304.34, feelsLike:
> 301.38, pressure: 1014, humidity: 13, dewPoint: 271.9, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.29, windDeg: 183, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601499600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 304.58, feelsLike:
> 301.36, pressure: 1013, humidity: 12, dewPoint: 271.52, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.48, windDeg: 151, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601503200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 304.48, feelsLike:
> 300.82, pressure: 1013, humidity: 12, dewPoint: 271.4, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.09, windDeg: 132, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601506800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 304.03, feelsLike: 299.8,
> pressure: 1013, humidity: 13, dewPoint: 272.04, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.06, windDeg: 130, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601510400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 300.26, feelsLike:
> 295.85, pressure: 1013, humidity: 18, dewPoint: 274.22, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.62, windDeg: 140, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601514000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 296.09, feelsLike:
> 291.46, pressure: 1015, humidity: 22, dewPoint: 273.71, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.79, windDeg: 153, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601517600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 294.45, feelsLike:
> 290.18, pressure: 1016, humidity: 24, dewPoint: 273.45, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.24, windDeg: 151, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601521200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 292.95, feelsLike:
> 288.87, pressure: 1017, humidity: 26, dewPoint: 273.15, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.94, windDeg: 152, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601524800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 291.67, feelsLike:
> 287.75, pressure: 1018, humidity: 28, dewPoint: 272.9, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.69, windDeg: 176, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601528400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 290.77, feelsLike:
> 286.95, pressure: 1018, humidity: 30, dewPoint: 272.65, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.59, windDeg: 198, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601532000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 289.91, feelsLike:
> 286.19, pressure: 1018, humidity: 31, dewPoint: 272.52, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.38, windDeg: 205, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601535600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 288.33, feelsLike:
> 285.37, pressure: 1019, humidity: 35, dewPoint: 272.56, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.36, windDeg: 200, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601539200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 287.81, feelsLike:
> 284.97, pressure: 1019, humidity: 36, dewPoint: 272.54, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.17, windDeg: 196, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601542800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 287.24, feelsLike:
> 285.09, pressure: 1019, humidity: 37, dewPoint: 272.37, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 0.15, windDeg: 229, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601546400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 287.0, feelsLike: 283.93,
> pressure: 1019, humidity: 38, dewPoint: 272.37, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 1.5, windDeg: 42, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601550000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 286.72, feelsLike: 283.0,
> pressure: 1020, humidity: 39, dewPoint: 273.04, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 2.45, windDeg: 56, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601553600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 286.31, feelsLike:
> 282.44, pressure: 1021, humidity: 45, dewPoint: 274.67, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.02, windDeg: 65, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601557200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 286.12, feelsLike:
> 282.47, pressure: 1021, humidity: 53, dewPoint: 276.97, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.23, windDeg: 67, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601560800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 288.85, feelsLike:
> 285.41, pressure: 1022, humidity: 52, dewPoint: 279.13, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 3.57, windDeg: 64, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601564400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 292.06, feelsLike:
> 288.41, pressure: 1023, humidity: 45, dewPoint: 280.04, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.13, windDeg: 65, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601568000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 294.81, feelsLike:
> 290.96, pressure: 1023, humidity: 37, dewPoint: 279.81, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.29, windDeg: 73, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601571600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 297.16, feelsLike:
> 292.98, pressure: 1022, humidity: 31, dewPoint: 279.43, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.61, windDeg: 78, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601575200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 298.92, feelsLike:
> 294.36, pressure: 1022, humidity: 28, dewPoint: 279.09, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 5.17, windDeg: 82, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601578800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 299.91, feelsLike:
> 295.12, pressure: 1021, humidity: 25, dewPoint: 278.51, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 5.26, windDeg: 93, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601582400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 300.4, feelsLike: 295.64,
> pressure: 1020, humidity: 23, dewPoint: 278.02, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 4.99, windDeg: 103, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601586000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 300.56, feelsLike: 295.8,
> pressure: 1019, humidity: 23, dewPoint: 277.8, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 5.04, windDeg: 110, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601589600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 300.24, feelsLike:
> 295.29, pressure: 1019, humidity: 23, dewPoint: 277.77, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 5.23, windDeg: 110, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601593200, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 299.16, feelsLike: 294.0,
> pressure: 1019, humidity: 26, dewPoint: 278.24, uvi: nil, clouds: 0,
> visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 5.76, windDeg: 104, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601596800, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 296.55, feelsLike:
> 291.34, pressure: 1019, humidity: 35, dewPoint: 280.25, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 6.47, windDeg: 95, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601600400, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 293.36, feelsLike:
> 288.17, pressure: 1020, humidity: 45, dewPoint: 281.38, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 6.71, windDeg: 94, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601604000, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 292.11, feelsLike:
> 286.49, pressure: 1021, humidity: 49, dewPoint: 281.3, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 7.37, windDeg: 100, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0)), OpenWeather.Current(dt:
> 1601607600, sunrise: nil, sunset: nil, temp: 290.93, feelsLike:
> 285.05, pressure: 1023, humidity: 54, dewPoint: 281.61, uvi: nil, clouds: 0, visibility: 10000, windSpeed: 7.85, windDeg: 104, weather:
> [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01N)], pop: Optional(0))], daily:
> [OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601402400, sunrise: 1601383240, sunset:
> 1601426059, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day: 297.29, min: 281.46, max:
> 299.98, night: 291.04, eve: 296.25, morn: 283.22), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 291.77, night: 285.61, eve: 292.14, morn:
> 277.07), pressure: 1022, humidity: 18, dewPoint: 267.94, windSpeed: 4.72, windDeg: 294, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 801, main: OpenWeather.Main.clouds, weatherDescription:
> OpenWeather.Description.fewClouds, icon: OpenWeather.Icon.the02D)],
> clouds: 14, pop: 0, uvi: 7.27), OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601488800,
> sunrise: 1601469681, sunset: 1601512377, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day:
> 302.28, min: 286.71, max: 304.58, night: 292.95, eve: 300.26, morn: 286.71), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 299.17, night: 288.87, eve: 295.85, morn: 281.98), pressure: 1016, humidity: 15, dewPoint:
> 272.68, windSpeed: 1.58, windDeg: 260, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], clouds: 0, pop: 0, uvi: 7.17),
> OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601575200, sunrise: 1601556123, sunset:
> 1601598695, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day: 298.92, min: 286.31, max:
> 300.56, night: 290.93, eve: 296.55, morn: 286.31), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 294.36, night: 285.05, eve: 291.34, morn:
> 282.44), pressure: 1022, humidity: 28, dewPoint: 279.09, windSpeed: 5.17, windDeg: 82, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear, weatherDescription:
> OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon: OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)],
> clouds: 0, pop: 0, uvi: 6.8), OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601661600,
> sunrise: 1601642565, sunset: 1601685013, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day:
> 298.22, min: 283.69, max: 300.93, night: 292.55, eve: 297.55, morn: 283.69), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 291.25, night: 287.4, eve: 292.2, morn: 280.29), pressure: 1018, humidity: 26, dewPoint:
> 277.74, windSpeed: 8.13, windDeg: 195, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], clouds: 8, pop: 0, uvi: 6.53),
> OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601748000, sunrise: 1601729008, sunset:
> 1601771332, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day: 301.18, min: 287.43, max:
> 304.98, night: 293.6, eve: 300.0, morn: 287.43), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 296.21, night: 288.26, eve: 298.01, morn:
> 283.24), pressure: 1010, humidity: 20, dewPoint: 276.76, windSpeed: 4.94, windDeg: 231, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear, weatherDescription:
> OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon: OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)],
> clouds: 1, pop: 0, uvi: 6.67), OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601834400,
> sunrise: 1601815451, sunset: 1601857651, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day:
> 299.81, min: 286.06, max: 303.41, night: 294.89, eve: 299.49, morn: 286.06), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 297.03, night: 290.22, eve: 296.39, morn: 285.09), pressure: 1016, humidity: 28, dewPoint:
> 280.2, windSpeed: 2.86, windDeg: 138, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], clouds: 0, pop: 0, uvi: 6.48),
> OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1601920800, sunrise: 1601901894, sunset:
> 1601943971, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day: 301.41, min: 288.91, max:
> 304.02, night: 295.44, eve: 299.96, morn: 288.91), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 294.87, night: 288.51, eve: 293.19, morn:
> 285.45), pressure: 1016, humidity: 26, dewPoint: 280.61, windSpeed: 8.32, windDeg: 202, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear, weatherDescription:
> OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon: OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)],
> clouds: 0, pop: 0, uvi: 6.81), OpenWeather.Daily(dt: 1602007200,
> sunrise: 1601988337, sunset: 1602030292, temp: OpenWeather.Temp(day:
> 302.74, min: 288.12, max: 306.48, night: 295.14, eve: 301.06, morn: 288.12), feelsLike: OpenWeather.FeelsLike(day: 299.07, night: 290.36, eve: 295.96, morn: 283.96), pressure: 1012, humidity: 16, dewPoint:
> 275.12, windSpeed: 2.64, windDeg: 237, weather: [OpenWeather.Weather(id: 800, main: OpenWeather.Main.clear,
> weatherDescription: OpenWeather.Description.clearSky, icon:
> OpenWeather.Icon.the01D)], clouds: 0, pop: 0, uvi: 6.68)])